# Vim integration with Aptana / Eclipse that includes usage of .vimrc files?

Tags: eclipse, vim, aptana

There are several vim plugins for Aptana/Eclipse, I'm wondering whether there are any well-integrated ones that also lets you make use of a .vimrc file and a .vim user folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclimd](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html) let's you embed Vim IN Eclipse. It is your real vim loading your own .vimrc. I think the embedding works only on Linux, on other platforms it will open a new gVim instance.

[Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) does load a .vrapperrc file but it won't support much of your lovingly customized .vimrc: for example I've ported only 16 lines of my 459 lines long .vimrc to my .vrapperrc

Comment: does Eclimd still let you use eclipse's outline?  vrapper seems to be more lightweight and maybe the closest - i.e. .vrapperrc is enough to do keybindings, but I do miss the plugins.

Comment: Yes, each time you `:w`rite your buffer Eclipse sees the changes and the outline is updated accordingly.

Comment: i've just tried installing and using eclimd, but I'm getting an "An outline is not available" message in the outline section for files opened using the embedded vim editor.  is this working for you, and did you do something to configure it?  

Vrapper doesn't have that issue, but the key bindings override is a bit buggy and the project doesn't look well-maintained.

Comment: As far as I know, vrapper is well maintained. I don't find it buggy, I find it a little lacking, though: it has most of the basics covered but I keep running into annoying limitations.

Comment: I've removed eclim a "long time" ago. I use Eclipse only for ActionScript 3 (with Flash Builder) and this language is sadly not supported by eclim. When I tried it with PHP and JavaScript, the outline was updated at each save. Now that I think about it, the outline was also updated when editing "unsupported" AS3 files. I didn't do anything special for it to work. What language do you work with?

Comment: strange.. i'm using php, and eclimd isn't showing an outline when i use the embedded vim editor.  i didn't notice vrapper moved to github recently, but i'll submit a ticket there for the bug i came across.

Comment: Embedding works in windows 7. It's not everything, the gvim window isn't completely rendered inside it's containing eclipse frame.